# Estrutura de um WebService X Classe de modelo

Tags: c#, web-service, asmx

Preciso fazer um web service (asmx) onde a Entrada da Requisição seja nessa estrutura:

**XML de Entrada (Request)**

```
<RetrieveDeviceParentRequest>
         <model query="">
            <keys query="">
               <ConfigurationItem type="String" ></ConfigurationItem>
               <ParentDevice type="String"></ParentDevice>
            </keys>
            <instance>
               <ConfigurationItem type="String"></ ConfigurationItem>
               <ParentDevice type="String" ></ParentDevice>
            </instance>
         </model>
      </RetrieveDeviceParentRequest>
```

**WebMethod** 
Hoje tenho esse Web Metodo que não atende o XML acima

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Device : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public DataTable RetrieveDevice(string RetrieveDeviceRequest)
    {
        DeviceBusiness objDeviceBusiness = new DeviceBusiness();
        return objDeviceBusiness.getDevice(RetrieveDeviceRequest);
    }
}
```

O que tenho que fazer ? 
 
O parametro de entrada deve ser um DataSet ao invés de tipo string ?

Não tenho o domínio e gostaria de ter mais tempo para pesquisar, porém a situação é crítica pois vão desligar o servidor e preciso fazer outro web service para substitui-lo.

Comment: Reformulei o post para ficar de melhor entendimento

Comment: Você não deveria envelopar essa estrutura em uma `RetrieveDeviceParentRequest`

Comment: Bom dia @Leandro Angelo o que seria "envelopar" ?, como disse não tenho domínio e o tempo é curto, no entanto contornei o problema atual mudando a assinatura do método web para: `public XmlDocument RetrieveClienteRequest(model model))`, mais ai me deparei com outro problema.

Answer (score 0):

Criei uma classe chamada **model**, **keys** e **instance** com os atributos de entrada:

Classe **model**:

```
public class model
    {
        public keys Keys { get; set; }
        public instance instance { get; set;}
    }
```

Classe **keys**:

```
public class keys
    {
        public string ConfigurationItem { get; set; }
        public string ParentDevice { get; set; }
    }
```

Classe **instance**:

```
public class instance
    {
        public string ConfigurationItem { get; set; }
        public string ParentDevice { get; set; }

    }

[WebMethod]
        public XmlDocument RetrieveClienteRequest(model model)
        {
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            ClienteBusiness objClienteBusiness = new ClienteBusiness();
            xmlDoc = objClienteBusiness.getCustomer(model);
            return xmlDoc;
        }
```

Não sei se é a melhor maneira mas resolveu o problema se alguém tiver outra alternativa agradeço os comentários.